# how to find completion time in SJF(NON-preemptive)scheduling?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, job-scheduling

can anyone help me?I tried this problem But I am not clear in this concept this is  a sjf nonpreemptive algorithm in OS. can anyone check this is right or not? I am  waiting for reply...thanks in advance..

```html
p   AT  BT  CT
P1  0   5   5
P2  2   3   11
P3  4   2   8
P4  6   4   15
P5  7   1   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link
http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/11/shortest-remaining-time-first-srt-preemptive-non-preemptive-sjf-scheduling-algorithm-with-example-java-program-code.html

```
Ans: P1 -> P3 -> P5 -> P2 -> P4
CT:  05 -> 07 -> 08 -> 11 -> 15 (Based on chart)
```

Based above link you can find out CT.

Other links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNsHRY5Nk5U

http://perugini.cps.udayton.edu/teaching/courses/cps346/lecture_notes/scheduling.html